# Python декораторы

Tags: python, python-3.x, декоратор

Каким образом функция `func()` передалась как аргумент в функцию `deco()` ?

```
ps = input("Введите пароль:")

def test_pass(p):
    def deco(f):
        if p == "universe":
            return f
        else:
            return lambda: "Access denied"
    return deco

@test_pass(ps)
def func():
    return "Access approval"

print(func())
```

Comment: related: [Understanding Python decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/4279)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Грубо говоря, Python разворачивает конструкцию

```
@test_pass(ps)
def func():
    ...
```

в

```
def func():
    ...

decorator = test_pass(ps)  # В два шага для понятности
func = decorator(func)
```

Answer (score 2):

В Питоне функции - это есть объекты. То есть мы можем сними делать всё, что сможем сделать с объектами. Например как в случае с декоратором. передавать объект функции как аргумент. так как `func` это есть объект функции, а `func()` вызов

```
ps = 'any argument'
decorator = test_pass(ps) # возращает объект внутренней функции deco.
func = decorator(func) # вызывается deco(f)
```