# python динамическая функция

Tags: python, функции

Задача состоит в том, что бы реализовать нечто подобное, но работоспособное

```
def magic_func(num):
    # Some magic stuff


for i in range(10):
    magic_func(i)


@magic_hook
def execute(num):
    print(num)
```

То есть, `magic_func` вызывается 10 раз и в кач-ве аргумента в неё передаётся целое число, над которым производятся определённые манипуляции
И! Результат передаётся в функцию, которая перед собой имеет `@magic_hook`

Comment: Зачем вам это? Расскажите, какую задачу вы решаете, для чего вам это понадобилось? А то я мало что понял, например

Comment: Хм.. Я пишу некую `multilib` библиотеку, которая импортируется в, допустим, `main.py`, задаются параметры, бла-бла-бла, после чего запускается функция `multilib.start()`, в которой что-то выполняется и на разных стадиях выполнения необходимо передавать данные уже в `processing.py` по средствам данного "хука"

Comment: Всё равно ничего не понял, просто вызывайте нужную функцию из `processing.py` в нужные моменты без всяких хуков да и всё, не?

Comment: Да, можно и так, но передав эту библиотеку, скажем, своему другу, ему нужно будет либо править мою `multilib` библиотеку
Или же иными способами извращаться, чего нет в PyTelegramBotApi, например

Comment: Передавайте нужную функцию как аргумент в `start` например, в PyTelegramBotApi именно так и делается, просто функция называется примерно как `message_handler` и оформлена в виде декоратора

Comment: @Alex: из комментариев, необходимую для ответа информацию прямо в ваш вопрос добавьте (вопрос должен быть ясен без комментариев). Есть кнопка [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по упоминанию PyTelegramBotApi в комментах, вы хотите что-то типа [паттерна Observer или Pub-Sub](https://habrahabr.ru/post/270339/). В самом примитивном виде это делается просто: передаём функцию на хранение нужному объекту, который будет потом вызывать её, когда сочтёт нужным. Ниже я написал пример класса, который позволяет подписаться на событие `secondchanged` и будет вызывать все обработчики, когда наступит следующая секунда:

```
import time

class SuperModule:
    def __init__(self):
        # В словаре храним разрешённые типы событий и их подписчиков
        self.subscriptions = {'secondchanged': []}

    def publish(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        # Рассылка информации о случившемся событии всем подписавшимся
        for callback in self.subscriptions[name]:
            callback(*args, **kwargs)

    def subscribe(self, name, callback):
        # Добавление обработчика определённого типа события
        # (в данном примере тип всего один — secondchanged)
        self.subscriptions[name].append(callback)

    def run(self):
        # Просто рабочая лошадка, отслеживающая секунды
        next_second = int(time.time()) + 1
        while True:
            time.sleep(next_second - time.time())
            # Когда дождались следующей секунды, запускаем событие
            self.publish('secondchanged', next_second)
            next_second += 1


def execute(tm):
    # Это будет обработчик, слушающий событие secondchanged
    print('Current second is {}'.format(tm % 60))


# Создаём наш крутой объект
m = SuperModule()
# Подписываем нашу функцию на нужное нам событие
m.subscribe('secondchanged', execute)
# И работаем до бесконечности
m.run()
```

Синтаксис вида `@bot.message_handler` из PyTelegramBotApi — это [самый обычный декоратор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767961/178213), который внутри себя вызовет тот же самый `subscribe`. В самом простом случае декоратор может выглядеть так:

```
import time

class SuperModule:

    # ... весь остальной код класса такой же ...

    def secondchanged_handler(self, func):
        # Это декоратор, который принимает функцию и подписывает её.
        # Возвращаемое значение станет той функцией, которую оборачивает
        # декоратор; мы с ней ничего, кроме вызова subscribe, не делаем
        # и возвращаем как есть
        self.subscribe('secondchanged', func)
        return func


# Создаём наш крутой объект
m = SuperModule()

# Создаём нашу крутую функцию и сразу же пихаем её в subscribe,
# используя наш декоратор

@m.secondchanged_handler
def execute(tm):
    print('Current second is {}'.format(tm % 60))

# Использование декоратора выше эквивалентно такому коду:
# execute = m.secondchanged_handler(execute)

# И работаем до бесконечности
m.run()
```

---

*Disclaimer: данный ответ является обзорным и не претендует на исчерпывающее руководство по декораторам и Observer/Pub-Sub; перед их использованием рекомендуется прочитать дополнительную информацию и best practices в интернете, а бездумно копипастить данный пример в свои проекты не стоит.*

Comment: не ясно причём тут observer и зачем pubsub самостоятельно реализовывать. Если хочется решение через паттерн, то strategy проще вариант. Вы же выше предложили уже решение: чтобы пользователям библиотеки автора вопроса не приходилось редактировать библиотеку, чтобы свою функцию подставить, которая некие параметры считает по динамическому вводу, то предоставьте им возможность передать их функцию как параметр (тривиально в Питоне). [python strategy pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8919545/4279)

Comment: @jfs автор хотел как в PyTelegramBotApi - я написал как в PyTelegramBotApi. И меня учили, что pubsub это разновидность observer (блин, зачем вообще нужны шаблоны, если все всё разными словами всё равно называют и ничего по-прежнему непонятно?)

Answer (score 0):

Из комментариев к вопросу:

> **Alex:** после чего запускается функция multilib.start(), в которой что-то выполняется и на разных стадиях выполнения необходимо передавать данные уже в processing.py по средствам данного "хука"
>   **andreymal:** просто вызывайте нужную функцию из processing.py в нужные моменты без всяких хуков да и всё...
>   **Alex:** Да, можно и так, но передав эту библиотеку, скажем, своему другу, ему нужно будет либо править мою multilib библиотеку

Не нужно править, достаточно, функцию, которую необходимо запускать с динамическим вводом, как параметр принимать. К примеру, код вашей библиотеки:

```
# magiclib.py
import random

def magic_func(num, execute):
    n = random.randrange(num)
    execute(n)
```

Код вашего друга:

```
import magiclib

magiclib.magic_func(10, print)
```